# EntityFramework and Auto Incrementing Solution Version Numbers

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a build server that auto increments the solution's version numbers when a checkin is done in git. However this is causing troubles with C# EntityFramework and code first migrations because of the encoded "model" column in the _MigrationHistory table. It stores the version of the assemblies in my project at the time the Add-Migration command is run.

So my issue is run the "Add-Migration" command, version 1.x gets stored in the generated migration files. Once the code gets checked in the auto incrementing build server stores the files at version 2.x -- which causes a version mismatch:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0004: Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly,  
Version=1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8555df3922cc0c82' or 
one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in EF 6.1.1. We were using EF 6.1.0.

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2051